# Cannot select the value from the Select list by keyboard when it is generated via smart fields

Tags: sapui5, sap-web-ide

I have defined a smart form with some smart fields. One of my smart fields is a Select:

```xml
<smartForm:GroupElement>
    <smartField:SmartField value="{Trade}" id="smartFieldTrade" textInEditModeSource="ValueList" mandatory="false">
        <smartField:configuration>
            <smartField:Configuration preventInitialDataFetchInValueHelpDialog="false" displayBehaviour="idAndDescription" controlType="selection"/>
        </smartField:configuration>
    </smartField:SmartField>
</smartForm:GroupElement>
```

This element has the following entry in the annotation file:

```xml
<Annotations Target="Metadata.DamageReport/TrashContainer">
    <Annotation Term="Common.Text" Path="TrashContainertxt">
        <Annotation Term="UI.TextArrangement" EnumMember="UI.TextArrangementType/TextOnly"/>
    </Annotation>
    <Annotation Term="Common.ValueListWithFixedValues" Bool="true"/>
    <Annotation Term="Common.ValueList">
        <Record>
            <PropertyValue Property="CollectionPath" String="TrashContainerHelpSet"/>
            <PropertyValue Property="Parameters">
                <Collection>
                    <Record Type="Common.ValueListParameterInOut">
                        <PropertyValue Property="LocalDataProperty" PropertyPath="TrashContainer"/>
                        <PropertyValue Property="ValueListProperty" String="Id"/>
                    </Record>
                    <Record Type="Common.ValueListParameterOut">
                        <PropertyValue Property="LocalDataProperty" PropertyPath="TrashContainertxt"/>
                        <PropertyValue Property="ValueListProperty" String="Name"/>
                    </Record>
                </Collection>
            </PropertyValue>
        </Record>
    </Annotation>
</Annotations>
```

The problem is in the WebIDE, I can select the values of this select by mouse or keyboard. However, after deploying in the SAP ABAP Repository, when I open the select by mouse and try to select the value by keyboard, the value does not set!

[image]

Here the first time value has been selected by mouse and 302 is set, but later with keyboard I cannot set 301 or 303! You can see the value will return back to 302 after pressing the enter on my keyboard.

Comment: I reported [here](https://answers.sap.com/questions/13231437/cannot-select-the-value-from-the-select-list-by-ke.html) as well.